# Taxonomy Filter only filtering 10 results

Tags: php, wordpress

In Wordpress, I have a website for an estate agents which has 3 taxonomies - For Sale, For Rent and Commercial. In the template, I have a while loop which does not limit the amount of properties filtered, though it has no pagination, rather it should be unlimited.

So I'm not sure why, but it is only showing 10.

Here's my code:

```
            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="entry-content">
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php printf( esc_attr__( 'Permalink to %s', 'toolbox' ), the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ) ); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    } ?>
                <div class="entry-info">
                <h1><?php the_title() ?>  <span class="price"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "_property_info_price", true); ?></span></h1>
                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?></a>
                </div>

                </div>
```

Also here is the website link which explains what I mean. In the backend, there is 21 properties created for the 'for sale' properties, but only 10 are showing. And the same in the search as well (From homepage).

http://www.james-hayward.com/property_type/for-sale/

Comment: What's the code above `?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>`? Do you have a query or args above it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default WordPress is showing the last 10 posts (see under settings > reading > "Blog pages show at most"). You can either change that setting or make you own custom query in your template page (See the [WP_Query documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for examples).

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you havn't specified amount of posts to show, so wordpress uses the value set in the admin-section, which by default is 10.
Either change that (In admin -> Settings -> Read), or specify how many posts you want to fetch in the query.

```
$args = array(
    /* taxonomy and post type args */
    posts_per_page => -1 // -1 is unlimited.
);

$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
if($the_query->have_posts()) : while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();
      /* Your markup and stuff goes here */
endwhile; endif;
```